# What prefix keys are allowable in tmux?

Tags: tmux

Lots of people modify their tmux prefix keys. Usually it's `Control+something`. But surely other things are possible.

I tried, for example, `,t`, but on starting tmux, I got the error `bad key: ,t`.

So what are the rules? **What prefixes are allowed in tmux?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be a *single* “key stroke”.

The basic set of recognized keys includes

- the ASCII characters (including the [C0 control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29)),
- the function keys: `F1`–`F20`,
- the movement keys: `Up`, `Down`, `Left`, `Right`, `Home`, `End`, `PageUp`, `PageDown`,
- the editing keys: `IC` (Insert), `DC` (Delete), and
- the keypad keys: `KP/`, `KP*`, `KP-`, `KP+`, `KP.`, `KPEnter`, `KP0`–`KP9`.

Not all terminals support sending unique sequences for all those keys; also, not all of those keys are described in every terminfo entry (indicated by the TERM environment variable when attaching to a *tmux* session). So, some of them might not be available in your particular setup.

If an Escape character precedes the sequence for one of the above keys, then it will be treated as a Meta modifier. This is represented as a `M-` prefix when naming the key (e.g. `M-F1`).

*tmux* also recognizes some special sequences that *xterm* can send when Shift, Control, and Meta are used with most of the non-ASCII keys (e.g. `S-C-M-Up`), but many terminals do not generate these sequences (or only support a limited set of modifiers for just the arrow keys).

Comment: I think recent versions support a much wider variety of keys - § seems to work on tmux 2.3 on macOS (but not on Linux on 1.8).